# Grouping records from LEFT JOIN in mysql if i already have ORDER BY statement and DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, and a query:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT assistent.id as id, 
  name, 
  events.client as client, 
  assistentprice.id as priceid, 
  value 
FROM 
  `assistents` 
  LEFT JOIN `events` ON assistents.id = events.assistent 
  LEFT JOIN `assistentprice` ON assistents.id = assistentprice.id_assistente 
ORDER BY 
  name
```

I got a result like:

| id | name | client | priceid | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88 | MARK | 44 | 12 | 7.00 |
| 88 | MARK | 27 | 14 | 8.00 |
| 88 | MARK | 44 | 15 | 11.00 |
| 88 | MARK | 27 | 11 | 10.00 |
| 88 | MARK | 44 | 10 | 9.00 |
| 16 | OSCAR | 49 | 21 | 8.00 |
| 16 | OSCAR | 14 | 23 | 9.00 |
| 16 | OSCAR | 14 | 22 | 7.00 |
| 16 | OSCAR | 49 | 19 | 9.00 |

So, table is ordered by name, but i want to see also ordered/grouped client for every assistent. For exampe, for Mark it have to be:

| id | name | client | priceid | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88 | MARK | **27** | 12 | 7.00 |
| 88 | MARK | **27** | 14 | 8.00 |
| 88 | MARK | **44** | 15 | 11.00 |
| 88 | MARK | **44** | 11 | 10.00 |

How can i do this?

Comment: What's the logic for this? how does MARK 44 12 7.00 become MARK 27 12 7.00? It would be useful to see source data as text..

Comment: Explain in details why the current output is transformed to shown needed output. What are the rules for needed grouping/ordering? Why `client` value in 1st row is changed from 44 to 27? Why 5th row for Mark is skipped? PS. The values seems to be NOT NULL - why you use LEFT joinig and not INNER?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to write that the order rule for client have to be numerically ASCENDING. And there was a mistake in table - now i have fixed it. So, it have to be ordered by name alphabetically and at the same time grouped by name numerically ASC

Comment: And please don't pay attetntion that last row for Mark is skipped. It is just a part of output. And in real tables there are some null values, so i use LEFT JOIN. Thanks

Comment: `ORDER BY name, client`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, forpas! And other guys, too